# Properly Overlaying Images in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, transparency

I'm programming a game in JavaScript and am running into a bit of a graphical roadblock; to draw the graphics onto the screen, I'm essentially creating a multi-dimensional array of tiles with images being drawn at each of the corresponding `(x, y)` coordinates on the canvas.  The array structure looks like this;

```
var tiles =
[
  [ [ [ src1, src2] ], [ [ src1, src2 ] ] ],
  [ [ [ src1, src2] ], [ [ src1, src2 ] ] ]
];
```

In the example above, the desired result would be a canvas split into four grid squares, each of which would be populated with the base layer `src1` and the transparent overlay layer `src2`.  So far, I've been able to accomplish this using the following code;

**JavaScript**

```
function drawCanvas(canvasID, tiles)
{
    let canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);

    canvas.height = Game.imageSize * tiles.length;
    canvas.width = Game.imageSize * tiles[0].length;

    for (let x = 0; x < tiles.length; x++)
    {
        for (let y = 0; y < tiles[x].length; y++)
        {
            fillCanvasCell(canvasID, { x: x, y: y }, tiles[x][y]);
        }
    }
}

function fillCanvasCell(canvasID, coords, tiles)
{
    let context = document.getElementById(canvasID).getContext("2d");

    context.clearRect(Game.imageSize * coords.y, Game.imageSize * coords.x, Game.imageSize, Game.imageSize);

    tiles.forEach(function(tile)
    {
        let image = new Image();
        image.onload = function()
        {
            context.drawImage(image, Game.imageSize * coords.y, Game.imageSize * coords.x);
        };
        image.src = tile;
    });
}
```

In this example, `Game.imageSize` is `100` (to represent the height/width in pixels of the graphics I'm using in the game).  As I said before, this works perfectly and accomplishes the task exactly as I want it to...

...with one exception; because the actual drawing of the graphics is done when the images load, sometimes they will load out of order and the base layer will be drawn over top of the transparent layer...

My question is this; what exactly can I do to prevent that from happening?  Do I need to completely revamp the way I'm drawing on these canvases?  Or do I just need to pre-load the images and then pull the pre-loaded images instead of having JavaScript make new images every time?